# How to schedule a batch apex for every 30mins

Tags: apex, schedulebatch

I have a usecase in which need to schedule a batch class for evert 30 mins.

Client denied to provide access to developer console in production.

What will be the other way to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to write two Cron expression to schedule it for every 30mins

Below cron schedules the batch every hour i.e. 12 PM, 1 PM and so on.

```
System.schedule('Hourly_Schedule', '0 0 * * * ?', new BatchClass1());
```

Below cron schedules the batch on every 30th min i.e. 12:30 PM, 1:30 PM and so on.

```
System.schedule('30Min_Schedule', '0 30 * * * ?', new BatchClass1());
```

You need to replace `BatchClass1` with your scheduler batch class name.

Execute the above code in the anonymous code execution in Developer console or through Workbench

> If Author Apex permission on profile is not enabled you can't execute
>   the code.

Comment: We do not have permission to run the code from anonymous code execution.

Comment: Can't you access Workbench?

Comment: Yes but what if any error occurs?

Comment: I don't think so there will be any issues in just scheduling the batch class unless your business logic in the batch class doesn't fail or throw error. Or else try to run this in some sandbox to execute the cron expr and check whether it throws any error

Comment: Once scheduled you can check under Setup > Enter Schedule jobs to check whether or not  job is been scheduled.